# Multi Tenancy in .NET 6 using Keycloak without restarting .NET application

Tags: .net, .net-core, keycloak, multi-tenant, keycloak-rest-api

I am trying to achieve multi tenancy in .NET 6 application for authorizing backend APIs.
I successfully achieve by adding multiple realms information (Issuer & Audience) in appSettings.json and jwt schemas inside program.cs file.
But my problem is, I want to achieve same multi tenancy when .NET application is in **running state**, because I don't want to **restart application (production)** when ever new realm created inside Keycloak.

I tried to inject newly created realm information into JWT Schema through ServiceCollection but unable to run it, because I am not allowing to inject new service during runtime of application.

I also tried to achieve it through middleware, I was able to add new middleware on runtime which is having schema of newly created realm, but it is still unable to identify schema.

Is there anyway to add multi tenancy support without rebuilding application?